# How to rename/hide CDN image urls

Tags: symfony, mod-rewrite, cdn

I have Symfony application where I show a list of images which are hosted on a CDN. I would like to hide the CDN's real path from the users. The specific part of the url which I would like to hide/rename is the static part of the url. The CDN's path is passed as source attribute to an `<img` tag.

The paths static part is similar to:

```
https://contents.xyz.acmecdn.net/v/
```

The dynamic part:

```
t31/720x720/7790141854625267503_o.jpg
```

What is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: How do you expect to hide it if you need to tell user's browser where to get image?

Comment: I mean hide the "real" path. I just don't want them to know that the image is hosted on acmecdn.

Comment: Why do you want to do something like this then?

Comment: @DarkBee I already said why. I don't want them to know the images are hosted on that specific CDN. My app basically gets data from another site which owns the CDN and exposing the real CDN might allow the users to know the source of the data i show.

Comment: Yeah but the only way to completely hide the reference to the CDN would be making your server download the images from the CDN and flush it back to your user which takes away the point of a CDN

Comment: What about using mod_rewrite to substitute the static part of the url with something like images/{dynamic_part}? What about encrpting the url?

Comment: Well if you use the mod_rewrite method the server will look for the content on your server. That why I said you'd need pull the images and server them. There is no such thing as encrypting an URL though